# Using SQL as Session Cache in Azure

Tags: asp.net, session, azure, caching, azure-sql-database

I am currently looking for the best way to use session caching in an Azure Webservice. Because multiple Instances are used, standard asp.net Session state does not work.

I found some documents that this can be solved by using an external session state provider which allows using a shared cache (Redis cache) or SQL as an external provider.

But while I found a lot of documentations how to configure the Redis cache, I did not find a single example how to configure an Azure-SQL-Database for caching.

If this is still supported in Azure: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
 <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
sqlConnectionString="Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=[password];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
cookieless="false" timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" />
```

A nicer solution is to use table storage, because you can specify the lifetime of an object in table storage.

more info: [managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/)

Comment: Can you elaborate any more on "A nicer solution is table storage"? Azure session state offerings have changed a lot in the last few years and that link you provided is a few years old. 
During my research I've seen various people saying that TS is slow, and I can't find *recent* examples of people using TS for session state handling

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing where you got with this as I have a similar requirement

Comment: You can find any example anymore because table storage is not supported anymore on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may avoid needing to know how to manually create the AspNetSessionState database objects:

1) Install NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers/2.0.0:

> ASP.NET Universal Providers add provider support in ASP.NET 4 for all editions of SQL Server 2005 and later and to SQL Azure. If you use these providers to develop your application, the application will be ready for cloud environments like Azure...

It has a dependency on `EntityFramework` but I guess we live with that. It adds this to your web.config `<system.web>` section:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

2) But for the release config you will want:

```
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider" connectionStringName="YourSessionConnectionStringName" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

where the `xdt:Transform="Replace"` is required if you use config transforms and must be removed if not.

and then the matching ConnectionString definition

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="YourSessionConnectionStringName" connectionString="server=SessionServer;database=SessionDb;uid=SessionUser;password=SessionUserPassword;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: and where is the cache persisted this way?

Comment: As per the ConnectionString section which I failed to include :-) 
The snippet I gave references `connectionStringName="YourSessionConnectionStringName"`

Answer (score 0):

The script below taken from [here](https://mariodivece.com/blog/2017/02/17/sql-azure-session-state) & [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariodivece/blog/master/2017-02-17-sql-azure-session-state/InstallSqlState.sql) will configure an Azure SQL database for ASP.NET session state.

Don't forget to figure out a way to call the DeleteExpiredSessions stored procedure regularly to get rid of the old sessions. You might be able to do this with the new elastic jobs. I happened to have SQL Server on a VM that I could call it from.

See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/using-sql-azure-for-session-state/) for some more details.

```
/*********************************************************************
 InstallSqlState.SQL                                                

 Installs the tables, and stored procedures necessary for         
 supporting ASP.NET session state on SQL Azure.                              

 Copyright Microsoft, Inc.
 All Rights Reserved.

 *********************************************************************/

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ASPStateTempSessions]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[ASPStateTempSessions]
GO  

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ASPStateTempApplications]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[ASPStateTempApplications]
GO  

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'GetMajorVersion') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].GetMajorVersion
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'CreateTempTables') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].CreateTempTables
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetVersion') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetVersion
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'GetHashCode') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].GetHashCode
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetAppID') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetAppID
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetStateItem') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetStateItem
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetStateItem2') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetStateItem2
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetStateItem3') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetStateItem3
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetStateItemExclusive') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetStateItemExclusive
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetStateItemExclusive2') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetStateItemExclusive2
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempGetStateItemExclusive3') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempGetStateItemExclusive3
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempReleaseStateItemExclusive') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempReleaseStateItemExclusive
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempInsertUninitializedItem') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempInsertUninitializedItem
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempInsertStateItemShort') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempInsertStateItemShort
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempInsertStateItemLong') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempInsertStateItemLong
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempUpdateStateItemShort') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempUpdateStateItemShort
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempUpdateStateItemShortNullLong') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempUpdateStateItemShortNullLong
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempUpdateStateItemLong') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempUpdateStateItemLong
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempUpdateStateItemLongNullShort') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempUpdateStateItemLongNullShort
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempRemoveStateItem') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempRemoveStateItem
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'TempResetTimeout') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].TempResetTimeout
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'DeleteExpiredSessions') AND (type = 'P')))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].DeleteExpiredSessions
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMajorVersion
    @@ver int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @version        nchar(100)
    DECLARE @dot            int
    DECLARE @hyphen      int
    DECLARE @SqlToExec   nchar(4000)

    SELECT @@ver = 7
    SELECT @version = @@Version
    SELECT @hyphen = CHARINDEX(N' - ', @version)
    IF (NOT(@hyphen IS NULL) AND @hyphen > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @hyphen = @hyphen + 3
        SELECT @dot = CHARINDEX(N'.', @version, @hyphen)
        IF (NOT(@dot IS NULL) AND @dot > @hyphen)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @version = SUBSTRING(@version, @hyphen, @dot - @hyphen)
            SELECT @@ver     = CONVERT(int, @version)
        END
    END
END
GO  

/*****************************************************************************/


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateTempTables
AS
    CREATE TABLE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions (
        SessionId         nvarchar(88)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Created          datetime       NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
        Expires          datetime       NOT NULL,
        LockDate            datetime        NOT NULL,
        LockDateLocal     datetime      NOT NULL,
        LockCookie       int             NOT NULL,
        Timeout          int             NOT NULL,
        Locked           bit             NOT NULL,
        SessionItemShort    VARBINARY(7000) NULL,
        SessionItemLong  image        NULL,
        Flags             int            NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ) 

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index_Expires ON dbo.ASPStateTempSessions(Expires)

    CREATE TABLE dbo.ASPStateTempApplications (
        AppId             int            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        AppName          char(280)    NOT NULL,
    ) 

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index_AppName ON dbo.ASPStateTempApplications(AppName)

RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetVersion
    @ver     char(10) OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @ver = "2"
    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetHashCode
    @input varchar(280),
    @hash int OUTPUT
AS
    /* 
      This sproc is based on this C# hash function:

        int GetHashCode(string s)
        {
            int  hash = 5381;
            int  len = s.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                int  c = Convert.ToInt32(s[i]);
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) ^ c;
            }

            return hash;
        }

        However, SQL 7 doesn't provide a 32-bit integer
        type that allows rollover of bits, we have to
        divide our 32bit integer into the upper and lower
        16 bits to do our calculation.
    */

    DECLARE @hi_16bit  int
    DECLARE @lo_16bit  int
    DECLARE @hi_t     int
    DECLARE @lo_t     int
    DECLARE @len        int
    DECLARE @i       int
    DECLARE @c       int
    DECLARE @carry   int

    SET @hi_16bit = 0
    SET @lo_16bit = 5381

    SET @len = DATALENGTH(@input)
    SET @i = 1

    WHILE (@i <= @len)
    BEGIN
        SET @c = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1))

        /* Formula:                     
          hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) ^ c */

        /* hash << 5 */
        SET @hi_t = @hi_16bit * 32 /* high 16bits << 5 */
        SET @hi_t = @hi_t & 0xFFFF /* zero out overflow */

        SET @lo_t = @lo_16bit * 32 /* low 16bits << 5 */

        SET @carry = @lo_16bit & 0x1F0000 /* move low 16bits carryover to hi 16bits */
        SET @carry = @carry / 0x10000 /* >> 16 */
        SET @hi_t = @hi_t + @carry
        SET @hi_t = @hi_t & 0xFFFF /* zero out overflow */

        /* + hash */
        SET @lo_16bit = @lo_16bit + @lo_t
        SET @hi_16bit = @hi_16bit + @hi_t + (@lo_16bit / 0x10000)
        /* delay clearing the overflow */

        /* ^c */
        SET @lo_16bit = @lo_16bit ^ @c

        /* Now clear the overflow bits */   
        SET @hi_16bit = @hi_16bit & 0xFFFF
        SET @lo_16bit = @lo_16bit & 0xFFFF

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    /* Do a sign extension of the hi-16bit if needed */
    IF (@hi_16bit & 0x8000 <> 0)
        SET @hi_16bit = 0xFFFF0000 | @hi_16bit

    /* Merge hi and lo 16bit back together */
    SET @hi_16bit = @hi_16bit * 0x10000 /* << 16 */
    SET @hash = @hi_16bit | @lo_16bit

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

DECLARE @cmd nchar(4000)

SET @cmd = N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetAppID
    @appName    varchar(280),
    @appId   int OUTPUT
    AS
    SET @appName = LOWER(@appName)
    SET @appId = NULL

    SELECT @appId = AppId
    FROM dbo.ASPStateTempApplications
    WHERE AppName = @appName

    IF @appId IS NULL BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN      

        SELECT @appId = AppId
        FROM dbo.ASPStateTempApplications WITH (TABLOCKX)
        WHERE AppName = @appName

        IF @appId IS NULL
        BEGIN
            EXEC GetHashCode @appName, @appId OUTPUT

            INSERT dbo.ASPStateTempApplications
            VALUES
            (@appId, @appName)

            IF @@ERROR = 2627 
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @dupApp varchar(280)

                SELECT @dupApp = RTRIM(AppName)
                FROM dbo.ASPStateTempApplications 
                WHERE AppId = @appId

                RAISERROR(''SQL session state fatal error: hash-code collision between applications ''''%s'''' and ''''%s''''. Please rename the 1st application to resolve the problem.'', 
                            18, 1, @appName, @dupApp)
            END
        END

        COMMIT
    END

    RETURN 0'
EXEC(@cmd)  
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetStateItem
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000) OUTPUT,
    @locked  bit OUTPUT,
    @lockDate  datetime OUTPUT,
    @lockCookie int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        @locked = Locked,
        @lockDate = LockDateLocal,
        @lockCookie = LockCookie,
        @itemShort = CASE @locked
            WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @length = CASE @locked
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
            ELSE NULL
            END
    WHERE SessionId = @id

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT [SessionItemLong] FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @id
    END

    RETURN 0

GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetStateItem2
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000) OUTPUT,
    @locked  bit OUTPUT,
    @lockAge    int OUTPUT,
    @lockCookie int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        @locked = Locked,
        @lockAge = DATEDIFF(second, LockDate, @now),
        @lockCookie = LockCookie,
        @itemShort = CASE @locked
            WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @length = CASE @locked
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
            ELSE NULL
            END
    WHERE SessionId = @id

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT [SessionItemLong] FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @id
    END

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetStateItem3
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000) OUTPUT,
    @locked  bit OUTPUT,
    @lockAge    int OUTPUT,
    @lockCookie int OUTPUT,
    @actionFlags int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        @locked = Locked,
        @lockAge = DATEDIFF(second, LockDate, @now),
        @lockCookie = LockCookie,
        @itemShort = CASE @locked
            WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @length = CASE @locked
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        /* If the Uninitialized flag (0x1) if it is set,
          remove it and return InitializeItem (0x1) in actionFlags */
        Flags = CASE
            WHEN (Flags & 1) <> 0 THEN (Flags & ~1)
            ELSE Flags
            END,
        @actionFlags = CASE
            WHEN (Flags & 1) <> 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
    WHERE SessionId = @id

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT [SessionItemLong] FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @id
    END

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000) OUTPUT,
    @locked  bit OUTPUT,
    @lockDate  datetime OUTPUT,
    @lockCookie int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        LockDate = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN @now
            ELSE LockDate
            END,
        @lockDate = LockDateLocal = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN @nowLocal
            ELSE LockDateLocal
            END,
        @lockCookie = LockCookie = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN LockCookie + 1
            ELSE LockCookie
            END,
        @itemShort = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @length = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @locked = Locked,
        Locked = 1
    WHERE SessionId = @id

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT [SessionItemLong] FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @id
    END

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive2
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000) OUTPUT,
    @locked  bit OUTPUT,
    @lockAge    int OUTPUT,
    @lockCookie int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        LockDate = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN @now
            ELSE LockDate
            END,
        LockDateLocal = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN @nowLocal
            ELSE LockDateLocal
            END,
        @lockAge = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(second, LockDate, @now)
            END,
        @lockCookie = LockCookie = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN LockCookie + 1
            ELSE LockCookie
            END,
        @itemShort = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @length = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @locked = Locked,
        Locked = 1
    WHERE SessionId = @id

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT [SessionItemLong] FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @id
    END

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive3
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000) OUTPUT,
    @locked  bit OUTPUT,
    @lockAge    int OUTPUT,
    @lockCookie int OUTPUT,
    @actionFlags int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        LockDate = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN @now
            ELSE LockDate
            END,
        LockDateLocal = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN @nowLocal
            ELSE LockDateLocal
            END,
        @lockAge = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(second, LockDate, @now)
            END,
        @lockCookie = LockCookie = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN LockCookie + 1
            ELSE LockCookie
            END,
        @itemShort = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @length = CASE Locked
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        @locked = Locked,
        Locked = 1,

        /* If the Uninitialized flag (0x1) if it is set,
          remove it and return InitializeItem (0x1) in actionFlags */
        Flags = CASE
            WHEN (Flags & 1) <> 0 THEN (Flags & ~1)
            ELSE Flags
            END,
        @actionFlags = CASE
            WHEN (Flags & 1) <> 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
    WHERE SessionId = @id

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT SessionItemLong FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @id
    END

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempReleaseStateItemExclusive
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @lockCookie int
AS
    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, GETUTCDATE()), 
        Locked = 0
    WHERE SessionId = @id AND LockCookie = @lockCookie

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempInsertUninitializedItem
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000),
    @timeout    int
AS  

    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    INSERT dbo.ASPStateTempSessions 
        (SessionId, 
         SessionItemShort, 
         Timeout, 
         Expires, 
         Locked, 
         LockDate,
         LockDateLocal,
         LockCookie,
         Flags) 
    VALUES 
        (@id, 
         @itemShort, 
         @timeout, 
         DATEADD(n, @timeout, @now), 
         0, 
         @now,
         @nowLocal,
         1,
         1)

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempInsertStateItemShort
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000),
    @timeout    int
AS  

    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    INSERT dbo.ASPStateTempSessions 
        (SessionId, 
         SessionItemShort, 
         Timeout, 
         Expires, 
         Locked, 
         LockDate,
         LockDateLocal,
         LockCookie) 
    VALUES 
        (@id, 
         @itemShort, 
         @timeout, 
         DATEADD(n, @timeout, @now), 
         0, 
         @now,
         @nowLocal,
         1)

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempInsertStateItemLong
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemLong  image,
    @timeout    int
AS  
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    INSERT dbo.ASPStateTempSessions 
        (SessionId, 
         SessionItemLong, 
         Timeout, 
         Expires, 
         Locked, 
         LockDate,
         LockDateLocal,
         LockCookie) 
    VALUES 
        (@id, 
         @itemLong, 
         @timeout, 
         DATEADD(n, @timeout, @now), 
         0, 
         @now,
         @nowLocal,
         1)

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempUpdateStateItemShort
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000),
    @timeout    int,
    @lockCookie int
AS  
    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, @timeout, GETUTCDATE()), 
        SessionItemShort = @itemShort, 
        Timeout = @timeout,
        Locked = 0
    WHERE SessionId = @id AND LockCookie = @lockCookie

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempUpdateStateItemShortNullLong
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemShort varbinary(7000),
    @timeout    int,
    @lockCookie int
AS  
    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, @timeout, GETUTCDATE()), 
        SessionItemShort = @itemShort, 
        SessionItemLong = NULL, 
        Timeout = @timeout,
        Locked = 0
    WHERE SessionId = @id AND LockCookie = @lockCookie

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempUpdateStateItemLong
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemLong  image,
    @timeout    int,
    @lockCookie int
AS  
    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, @timeout, GETUTCDATE()), 
        SessionItemLong = @itemLong,
        Timeout = @timeout,
        Locked = 0
    WHERE SessionId = @id AND LockCookie = @lockCookie

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempUpdateStateItemLongNullShort
    @id      nvarchar(88),
    @itemLong  image,
    @timeout    int,
    @lockCookie int
AS  
    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, @timeout, GETUTCDATE()), 
        SessionItemLong = @itemLong, 
        SessionItemShort = NULL,
        Timeout = @timeout,
        Locked = 0
    WHERE SessionId = @id AND LockCookie = @lockCookie

    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempRemoveStateItem
    @id  nvarchar(88),
    @lockCookie int
AS
    DELETE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    WHERE SessionId = @id AND LockCookie = @lockCookie
    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TempResetTimeout
    @id  nvarchar(88)
AS
    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, GETUTCDATE())
    WHERE SessionId = @id
    RETURN 0
GO

/*****************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions
AS
    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()

    DELETE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    WHERE Expires < @now

    RETURN 0
GO 

/*****************************************************************************/

EXECUTE dbo.CreateTempTables
GO

/*************************************************************/
/*************************************************************/
/*************************************************************/
/*************************************************************/

PRINT ''
PRINT '------------------------------------------'
PRINT 'Completed execution of InstallSqlState.SQL'
PRINT '------------------------------------------'
```